# My Monitor is completely black, but Windows (11) recognizes it

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am having a problem in a new Lenovo laptop.

I am using a monitor in my house to use as my main display but it is completely black. The laptop recognizes everything about the monitor (an HP 25X, 144hz) but the monitor doesn't seem to recognize any input.

I've tried a couple of HDMI cords, restarted the laptop, installed the latest AMD graphic drivers etc. with no avail.

I have my main PC (desktop) attached with a DisplayPort and it works (and also works via HDMI), so the monitor is not faulty.

Any input? (no pun intended)

---

UPDATE:

- Sent to Lenovo under warranty for repair, probable hardware issue.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue with the monitor. Most likely the backlight has failed. It may be time for a new one.

Comment: try ur monitor with some anothor pc. If its working then reinstall windows in your laptop. I had similar problem with AMD graphics drives where HDMI not working so I start using VGA port for long time.

Comment: shine a bright light at the screen. If the backlight has failed, you can see an image

Comment: Hi guys! Thanks for the response, I have my main PC (desktop) attached with a DisplayPort and it works (and also works via HDMI), so the monitor is not faulty!

Comment: If you right-click on the desktop and choose "Display settings", what is "Multiple displays" set to?

Comment: Extend screens. It recognizes both. If I make a Google Meet call, I can see the screen if I am sharing it. It looks like the problem is with the laptop sending info to the monitor.